# Can I style <dt> directly within the tags?

Tags: html, css

I've inherited a project that contains a small web UI, which is a completely foreign land for me.
Elements are displayed using the `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags that are styled using a CSS.
However, in one particular place, I would need to make the `<dt>` width much larger,. 20 em. Can I do that directly in the tag?
I tried somethinh like `<dt width:20em>` but that does not work, and I was not able to find any examples.

Comment: Give `<dt style="width: 20em;">` a shot.

Comment: Why wouldn't you assign this special case a `class` and then write a rule for it in your CSS file?